# what is the right way to do conditional patterns in dust.js

Tags: node.js, templating, dust.js

When developing using node.js with express and the dustjs templating engine,
what would be the pattern to use to display a "Hello Username" menu v.s.  a Login form depending on wather the request is authenticated?

Should it be a template that uses conditionals? or would it be better to use two different templates and select the appropriate one based on the user's authentication status? or maybe some other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

I think e answer depends on the complexity of the different components. If the logged in menu and the login form are both relatively simple, they could easily be included in a single partial. If they are complex (or you suspect they may become more complex in the future), then breaking them out into separate "partials" may be the best approach. Extra templates come with a small overhead cost, but it is pretty minimal.

Additionally, if you start out with a single template and things start to get complex, it is pretty easy to break things out into separate partials.